# Surprising results with std::fstream

Tags: c++, visual-c++, text, io, fstream

I wrote a short program to generate evenly-spaced random digits and save them to a generic text file. If I ask it to generate exactly 786432 digits (spaces every six digits) the output displays as random Chinese and Japanese characters. Why?
I'm using standard-library classes for file I/O and 64-bit Xorshift as my PRNG.

The program (compiled under MSVC):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

// From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift
uint64_t xorsh64star(uint64_t* state)
{
    uint64_t x = *state;
    x ^= x >> 12;
    x ^= x << 25;
    x ^= x >> 27;
    state[0] = x;
    return x * 0x2545F4914F6CDD1D;
}

int main()
{
    uint64_t nDigits = 0;
    uint64_t wordLen = 1;
    std::cout << "How many digits?\n";
    std::cin >> nDigits;
    std::cout << "How many digits/word?\n";
    std::cin >> wordLen;
    std::fstream* txt = new std::fstream("randTxt.txt", std::ios::out);
    std::cout << "writing...";
    uint64_t charCtr = 0;
    uint64_t xorshState = 1103515245U; // GLIB C init constant, from https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XlXcW4
    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < nDigits; i += 1)
    {
        uint64_t rnd = xorsh64star(&xorshState) % uint64_t(9);
        *txt << rnd;
        charCtr += 1;
        if (!(charCtr % wordLen) && charCtr != 1)
        {
            *txt << ' ';
            charCtr += 1;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "finished! :D";
    return 0;
}
```

Output with 786431 digits:
[image: 786431 digits, six digits/space]

Output with 786432 digits:
[image: 786432 digits, six digits/space]

Output with 786433 digits:
[image: 786433 digits, six digits/space]

Comment: Why are you using `new` to create the `fstream`? That's unusual. You also don't use `delete` so the file stream probably isn't flushed and closed nicely.

Comment: I ran your program (thanks for providing a complete running example!) and tried 786431, 786432, and 786433 (with 6 digits per word....) I _so_ wanted to repeat your output! But, alas, on my Mac with C++ 14 with Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5), I got regular decimal digits for all three attempts.

Comment: I reproduced the problem on my machine. The file looks garbled in Windows notepad.exe. When I open it in any other text editor (Notepad++, wordpad.exe, or Visual Studio editor) it looks okay.

Comment: @Blastfurnace No idea how I missed that, thank you!
In my degree we were taught to assume `new` for everything non-trivial. I did it here because I didn't know where characters would buffer otherwise (since someone could easily output gigabytes of text...). I'm probably being silly though.
@RayToal Freeing the stream patches it out for me; it must have just been leftover data messing with subsequent outputs, and clang + the mac c++ runtime are architected in a way that stops that happening.

Comment: Yep! Thanks for the fix :)

Comment: EDIT: not actually a fix unfortunately, I think I put in the wrong values when I was testing blastfurnace's suggestion

Comment: @Blastfurnace Same here, compiled on MSVS17, on Win 10, 64 bit. Other editors (including VS) show it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the fix. I'm not sure what causes the original problem, but once the `if` statement is changed to:

```
if (!(charCtr % wordLen) && charCtr != 1
{
    txt << ' ';
//  charCtr += 1;    // This makes each word after the first 1 digit shorter.
}
```

the final .txt file is now shown properly, which fixes your notepad viewing problem **and** all your words now have 6 digits, not just the first one.

[image]

Originally, I reproduced the same problem by compiling your code with MSVS17 on Win 10 64bit:

[image]

Comment: Wow, that's a surprising fix. Thanks though! It definitely sounds like something to do with how spaces are pushed into the file and the text formatting expected by notepad, but I have no idea what in particular.

Comment: (+ thanks for patching the character offsets as well, I thought something looked off there)

Answer (score 1):

The answer below is helpful but didn't actually correct the reported issue. The problem was only seen with the Windows notepad.exe editor. It incorrectly displayed the file in a very specific instance. In any case I hope someone finds the answer below useful.

---

Using `new` to create the file stream looks unusual and isn't necessary in this code. Doing that also means you would need to use `delete` to properly flush, close, and destroy the stream object.

Replace this:

```
std::fstream* txt = new std::fstream("randTxt.txt", std::ios::out);
```

with:

```
std::fstream txt("randTxt.txt", std::ios::out);
```

and your writes will look like:

```
txt << rnd;
```

When the stream object goes out of scope it will nicely close the file and release any resources it held.

Comment: So...this is a bit awkward, but I just tested again and I got the same output as the first time. I think I put the wrong number of digits in when I tested without `new` before :|

Comment: I honestly think it's related to using notepad.exe. I saw the same thing but the text file appears fine when opened in any other text editor. Try opening randTxt.txt with the Visual Studio editor.

Comment: Wow, you're right. I never thought notepad'd trip up on specific character counts like that :O.

Comment: Well, I guess this answer is technically correct but doesn't answer the question. Bummer.

Comment: Haha, yeah. The only "correct" thing to do is filing a bug report though, so idk if it matters that much. "Don't put fstream on the heap" is still more useful advice generally than "you found a notepad bug".